# What would be the price of Adamantine Plate armor?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, armor, pricing, special-materials

I'm already aware, as per [Are there price lists for magic items, such as the Bag of Holding?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/83904/are-there-price-lists-for-magic-items-such-as-the-bag-of-holding), that 5e was designed with the assumption that magic items are not to be bought or sold willy-nilly. This doesn't happen to be true in my setting.

I'm also aware, as per [Do magic items really cost at least as much to create as they do to purchase?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/60478/do-magic-items-really-cost-at-least-as-much-to-create-as-they-do-to-purchase), that crafting new magical items is not a worthwhile effort in settings where magic items can be purchased - creating an item is more expensive than outright buying it.

My issue is different: What if the value of a *non-magic item* is higher than its *magic equivalent*? In my specific case, I had an issue with the price of *Adamantine Plate Armor* and the price of regular, unenhanced *Plate Armor*. DMG page 135 sets up price ranges for categories of items: Uncommon items would be priced in the 101-500 gp range. Adamantine Armor, which can be any sort of Medium or Heavy armor apart from Hide, is one such item. But Plate armor (which is a sort of Heavy armor) costs 1500 gp (according to PHB page 145).

My ruling on the spot was that the 101-500 gp range was for the reinforcement only, and not for the armor itself, and thus the Adamantine Plate armor would be priced at around 2000 gp. Is there another way of coming to an answer that I didn't consider?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: Related on [Can you coat a weapon with Adamantine?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/133220/can-you-coat-a-weapon-with-adamantine). Technically not a duplicate because it's asking about weapons and not armor.

Comment: Related: [How much gold and how much time does fitted mithril or adamantine armor cost?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/176591)

Comment: Preserving the related: [Do magic items really cost at least as much to create as they do to purchase?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/60478), [How much does Plate Armor of Gleaming cost?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/132090)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## 2000g sounds reasonable.

I like to use this [Sane Magic Prices](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8XAiXpOfz9cMWt1RTBicmpmUDg/view) guide. It is a popular resource, albeit fan-made. The authors have tried to list prices of items with a more sound reasoning. In it,

> All items which are weapons or armor add the cost of the base weapon or armor that makes them up to their price.

And Adamantine Armor is listed at 500g. So, an Adamantine Plate Armor would cost 2000g. It matches your own logic of paying 500g for the *reinforcement* of an armor.

Comment: Ooh, this is very useful! Thank you so much! It may be fan-made, but so would any other homebrew solution I might come up with, and this at least seems to be in keeping with the general feel of the game.